# Как поднять текст вверх, если мешают отступы другого текста?

Tags: html, css

```css
.text1 {
  margin-right: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
}

.text2 {
  padding-left: 650px;
  padding-bottom: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1 class='text1'>Текст 1</h1>
  <h2 class='text2'>Текст 2 <br>сообщение</br>
  </h2>
</div>
```

**надо "текст 2" поднять вверх до уровня "текст 1"**

Comment: Даже представить трудно, что именно автор хочет реализовать... Лучше опиши нормально и убери эти кошмарные падинги ...

Comment: А зачем такие огромные отступы? Если вы хотели чтобы блок занимал какое-то доп. пространство тогда задавайте конкретную ширину (`width`) и высоту (`height`), а такие отступы делать не надо. Если же вас всё устраивает, тогда просто используйте - `bottom: НИЖНИЙ_ВУНТУРНЕННИЙ_ОТСТУПpx`, что-то типа такого: `.text2 { position: relative; bottom: 150px; }`.

Answer (score -2):

У нижнего блока текста задайте `margin-top: -100px` (значение 100 поменяйте на нужное)

Comment: И все, `текст 2 && текст 1` встанут на один уровень???

Comment: И как это поможет? Вы не дали никакого объяснения... Да ещё и использовали `margin-top`...